# Does update query updates all the records in one shot or 1 by 1 in MySql?

Tags: sql, database

When we run a simple update command like

`update set featurenabled = true from accounts where deviceId = "testDevice"`

Does it lock all the rows where deviceId is testdevice and update the feature enabled 1 by 1 for each row?

Or does it updates all the records in 1 shot after acquiring the lock?

Comment: Add dbms tag, becuase this can be product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the database and the database engine and the indexes on the table.
For example I found that for MySQL(InnoDB engine), if you do:

```
update set featurenabled = true from accounts where deviceId = "testDevice"
```

Then:

- if you **don't have an index** on `deviceId`, then it locks the whole table
- if you **have a unique index** on `deviceId`, then it only locks the row where `deviceId="testDevice"`
- if you **have a non-unique index** on `deviceId`, then it locks all the rows where `deviceId="testDevice"`

So it depends on many things. I suggest you do a targeted search for your desired database type/engine, if you want to learn further about this topic.

And whether update happens in **1 shot**, or **row by row**, for MySQL, as I know, by default, the update statement is wrapped in a transaction, so you could say it happens in **1 shot**